# Jenkins can't fetch pull requests from git and svn

Tags: git, svn, github, jenkins

Hello yesterday my jenkins became crazy, i have got some projects, one of them configured to fetch pull requests from git, and the second one to ask the svn repo every five minutes. Yesterday this builds failed and jenkins can't fetch pull requests on git and svn.

For git i try to to specify branchspecifier `(was ${sha1}) like **`. And as i see it's start working, but it's not a good solution i think. 
For svn repository i really can't understand what to do, when i try to run it by myself it's ok, but request none.

Comment: Post any log exceptions or errors you got.

Comment: There were no logs(. like everything is ok.  just broke and nothing

Comment: Your guess git and svn using jenkins do not work anymore must be based on something. There must be a log for your build.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in Jenkins time, jenkins was working in future. Reboot jenkins service resolve the issue